# Order a sequence of dates as they occur in calendar year

Tags: python, perl, bash, sed, awk

I've got a series of pipes to convert dates in a text file into unique, human readable output and pull out `MM DD`. Now I would like to resort the output so that the dates display in the order in which they occur during the year. Anybody know a good technique using the standard shell or with a readily installable package on *nix?

```
Feb 4
Feb 5
Feb 6
Feb 7
Feb 8
Jan 1
Jan 10
Jan 11
Jan 12
Jan 13
Jan 2
Jan 25
Jan 26
Jan 27
Jan 28
Jan 29
Jan 3
Jan 30
Jan 31
Jan 4
Jan 5
Jan 6
Jan 7
Jan 8
Jan 9
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a utility called `sort` with an option `-M` for sorting by month. If you have it installed, you could use that. For instance:

```
sort -k1 -M test.txt
```

- `-k1`: First column
- `-M`: Sort by month

Edited per twalberg's suggestion below:

```
sort -k1,1M -k2,2n test.txt
```

Comment: Not all implementations of `sort` will support the `-M` option, but it is useful if available.

Comment: You might want to do `-k1M -k2n` instead.

Comment: To improve on that a bit, I would suggest `sort -k1,1M -k2,2n`. The reason is that `-k1` means to sort on a key *starting* with field 1 and extending to the rest of the line, and may not produce ideal results. Better to make it explicit that field 1 is to be sorted by month and field 2 as a numerical value (otherwise you might get 10 before 1, etc...).

Comment: Yes, that would be smarter.

Answer (score 1):

In two steps:

```
$ while read line; do date -d "$line" "+%Y%m%d"; done < file | sort -n > temp
$ while read line; do date -d "$line" "+%b %d"; done < temp > file
```

Firstly we convert dates to `YYYYMMDD` and order them:

```
$ while read line; do date -d "$line" "+%Y%m%d"; done < file | sort -n > temp
$ cat temp
20130101
20130102
20130103
20130104
20130105
20130106
20130107
20130108
20130109
20130110
20130111
20130112
20130113
20130125
20130126
20130127
20130128
20130129
20130130
20130131
20130204
20130205
20130206
20130207
20130208
```

Then we print them back to previous format `%b %d`:

```
$ while read line; do date -d "$line" "+%b %d"; done < temp > file
$ cat file
Jan 01
Jan 02
Jan 03
Jan 04
Jan 05
Jan 06
Jan 07
Jan 08
Jan 09
Jan 10
Jan 11
Jan 12
Jan 13
Jan 25
Jan 26
Jan 27
Jan 28
Jan 29
Jan 30
Jan 31
Feb 04
Feb 05
Feb 06
Feb 07
Feb 08
```

Comment: I accepted this solution because it was fast, effective, and relied on a minimal toolset. However, I consider all of the answers I have seen thus far to be legitimate and of high quality.

Answer (score 0):

and     sed -n "1 {
       H
       x
       s/.*(\n).*/01 Jan\102 Feb\103 Mar\104 Apr\105 May\106 Jun\107 Jul\105 Aug\109 Sep\110 Oct\111 Nov\112 Dec/
       x
       }

```
s/^\(.\{3\}\) \([0-9]\) *$/\1 0\2/
H

$  {
x

t subs
: subs
   s/^\([0-9]\{2\}\) \([[:alpha:]]\{3\}\)\(\n\)\(.*\)\n\2/\1 \2\3\4\3\1 \2/
   t subs
   s/^[0-9]\{2\} [[:alpha:]]\{3\}\n//
   t subs
   p
   }
" | sort | sed "s/^[0-9][0-9] //"
```

still need a sort (or a lot more complex sed for sorting) and when `sort -M` doesn't work